# The right way to describe "having proven credentials" in a resume

Tags: vocabulary

I need to write in short form in a resume that the person is a highly skilled and valued psychologist with proven "credentials" (in the form of recognition awards from his workplace, excellent personal recommendations, great performance reviews, etc.).

I thought about "proven credentials" and "proven abilities" but it sounds too specific to my ears.

Can anyone help me find a more accurate phrasing?

Comment: Since you're only supposed to provide information in a resume that is true and verifiable, I would **avoid** mentioning that some parts are "proven". It may give the suggestion that the rest of the resume is not. For the type of things you want to mention you could call them "recognition" or "acknowledgements", maybe?

Comment: @oerkelens what I mean is that this part is hard to test empirically (as opposed to theoretical knowledge for example). Therefore, I want to suggest that this person can still provide proof for that in the form of written credentials, performance reviews, awards, written recommendations and managers and peers that can vouch for it.

Comment: Personally I would take out all the superlatives. People experienced at reading these things are likely to be unimpressed. In the days when I read CVs I was interested simply to see what the candidate had actually done. Presenting oneself like an advertisement for a circus has serious drawbacks.  Modesty is a powerful and impressive force.

Comment: Anything for which you do not have proof you should not put on that resume. If I read a resume I assume you can prove every single claim on it.

Comment: You are all correct, but it's a matter of choice right? The fact that it's for a resume is just there for context, and either way, I'm still curious of what would be the right choice of words...

Comment: I'd say it's best to name each category, e.g. *certificates and references* ; to say that you have those: *certificates and references available upon request* somewhere at the and of the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [**established**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/established) *verb*: shown to be valid beyond a reasonable doubt; "the *established* facts in the case"; see, TFD

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly the word I was after :)

Answer (score 0):

How about saying that the person is "capable" (as a more concise adjective than talking about having capabilities), "[well-]recognized," or "highly regarded?"

Better yet, especially if it's that person's resume, drop the description and "show, don't tell" by listing those credentials and letting them speak for themselves!